# Is there a way to change the path to an application?

Tags: facebook

Question in title. When I created the application I left the default instead of a name and the application is now using the app. Id in the URL. Is there a way to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go to your app settings dashboard and change the namespace of the app - this will also represent your app's new URL.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will test it and confirm if this works ;)